# How to populate a collection view with buttons dynamically with array IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, dynamic-data

Hey guys first of all this project is in Objective-C Xcode for IOS.

I want to create a collection view with buttons dynamically generated according to a list of fruits I have and all buttons have different images. It would be in a column of 3.

Please help me out, thanks in advance.

Comment: Read out from here http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/   and from here https://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):